# Javascript DOM capturing after using javascript to insert dom

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a question regarding DOM manipulation, say I insert a grid using this function:

```
const grid__container = document.querySelector('.grid__container');

function createVertexes() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        const grid = document.createElement("div");
        grid.setAttribute('class', "vertex");
        grid.setAttribute('id', i+1);
        grid__container.appendChild(grid);

    }
}
```

afterwards, I try to grab all the vertexes with the class "vertex" using document.querySelectorAll("vertex") it doesnt work:

```
const vertexes = document.querySelectorAll('.vertex');
```

console log of this returns:

```
[]
```

but this works:

```
const vertexes = grid__container.childNodes;
```

console.log of this actually returns all 9 divs

I see that the difference is that grid__container is pre-defined in my HTML file, but I wrote the querySelectorAll method in a top down approach, so I dont understand why query selector doesnt work, because I created the elements then tried to grab it, anyone knows why?

I only know this is called DOM-manipulation and not know the exact name of this error and am quite new to javascript, please help.

I expected the console to log out 9 divs, but my vertexes here using querySelectorAll instead logs out a nodelist of length 0  `<NodeList: length 0>`

```js
// grab the main container 
const grid__container = document.querySelector('.grid__container');
const mole = document.querySelector(".mole");

const timeLeft = document.querySelector("#time__left");
const score = document.querySelector("#score");


let result = 0;


function createVertexes() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    const grid = document.createElement("div");
    grid.setAttribute('class', "vertex");
    grid.setAttribute('id', i + 1);
    grid__container.appendChild(grid);

  }
}

// const vertexes = grid__container.childNodes;
const vertexes = document.querySelectorAll('.vertex');
console.log(vertexes);

function randomSquare() {
  vertexes.forEach(vertex => {
    vertex.classList.remove('mole')
    console.log(vertex);
  })

  let randomVertex = vertexes[Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)]
  randomVertex.classList.add('mole');

}

createVertexes();
randomSquare();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid__container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.vertex {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: solid black 1px;
}

.mole {
  background-color: burlywood;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Whac-a-mole</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
  <script src="./app.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Your score:</h2>
  <h2 id="score">Score</h2>

  <h2>Time left:</h2>
  <h2 id="time__left">Time left</h2>
  <div class="grid__container"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you just need to use proper selctor, like `const vertexes = document.querySelectorAll('.vertex');`

Comment: There is a typo in your `qeurySelectorAll` spelling, should be `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: @MaciejKwas Thanks for replying! I'm sorry there was a typo in my post. But I tried using querySelectorAll in my IDE.  and my const vertex turns out to be an empty array instead

Comment: @sasaasasasha PR7’s comment referred to `qeurySelectorAll`, not `querySelectorALL`. The real issue is still the selector. Do you have `<vertex>` elements? How do they relate to the elements with the `vertex` class? The class selector is `.vertex`, not `vertex`.

Comment: @sasaasasasha You failed to provide a [mre]. This easily justifies a downvote.

Comment: If you do not post the actual situation but TWICE spell the selector and code wrong, what do you expect? That we guess your wrote everything correctly? We can only see what you post

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Move your app.js to just before the `</body>` tag. It is referring to elements that do not exist at execution time

Comment: @mplungjan No, that’s what the `defer` is for.

Comment: You have this `const vertexes = document.querySelectorAll('.vertex');` outside of any function, it executes before you have even called `createVertexes`.

Comment: Thanks, the code does work. But I needed to call the function to createVertex to create the classes first before i console log it. It was an order mistake, (I had to call the function to create vertex before i console log it out) and not a spelling mistake. I apologise to all for making spelling mistakes in my post. But theres nothing wrong with my code in the spelling in my code snippet. Thanks for enlightening me about minimal reproducible code.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you so much that was my error. Thanks for pointing it out to me

Comment: I missed the defer. I do not recommend it for obvious documentation purposes.

Comment: @mplungjan Could you elaborate more about documentation purposes? Sorry it's not obvious to someone new like me.

Comment: I have personally never used defer, but see it works the same way as `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"`  - when I see `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"` then I KNOW the script inside it has to run AFTER DOM has parsed. but as you see I easily missed the `defer` attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works if you spell everything correctly and run the code AFTER the DOM is complete AND get the vertexes at the time you need them

Also the .mole is not available until after the randomSquare has run

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // grab the main container 
  const grid__container = document.querySelector('.grid__container');
  const timeLeft = document.querySelector("#time__left");
  const score = document.querySelector("#score");
  let result = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    const grid = document.createElement("div");
    grid.setAttribute('class', "vertex");
    grid.setAttribute('id', i + 1);
    grid__container.appendChild(grid);
  }

  function randomSquare() {
    const vertexes = document.querySelectorAll('.vertex');
    vertexes.forEach(vertex => {
      vertex.classList.remove('mole')
    })
    let randomVertex = vertexes[Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)]
    randomVertex.classList.add('mole');
  }
  randomSquare();
  
  //   const mole = document.querySelector(".mole");

  
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid__container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.vertex {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: solid black 1px;
}

.mole {
  background-color: burlywood;
}
```

```html
<h2>Your score:</h2>
<h2 id="score">Score</h2>

<h2>Time left:</h2>
<h2 id="time__left">Time left</h2>
<div class="grid__container"></div>
```